# extra white space to the right of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I am trying to depict more than one matrix with tikz with the tikz libraries matrix and matrix.skeleton. Later I want to make use of the highlight features from matrix.skeleton on both matrix.

This would be my mwe:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix.skeleton}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}


\matrix (X) [matrix of math nodes,
            label skeleton,
             left delimiter  = (,
             right delimiter = )] at (0,0)
{%
  \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots  \\
  x & x & \cdots & x \\
  \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots  \\
  x & x & \cdots & x\\
  \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots  \\
  x & x & \cdots & x\\
  \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots  \\
  x & x & \cdots & x\\
  \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots  \\
  x & x & \cdots & x\\
};

\matrix (U) [matrix of math nodes,
            label skeleton,
             left delimiter  = (,
             right delimiter = )] at (4.5,0)
{
  \vdots  \\
  u\\
  \vdots \\
  u\\
  \vdots \\
  u\\
  \vdots \\
  u\\
  \vdots \\
  u\\
};

\fitandstyle{(X-cell-2-1) (X-cell-6-4)}{draw=red, fill=red!25, opacity=0.5}
\fitandstyle{(U-cell-4-1) (U-cell-8-1)}{draw=red, fill=red!25, opacity=0.5,xshift=-4.5cm}

\draw[red,dashed] (X-cell-2-4.north east) -- ($(U-cell-4-1.north west)+(-4.5cm,0)$);
\draw[red,dashed] (X-cell-6-4.south east) -- ($(U-cell-8-1.south west)+(-4.5cm,0)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: outcome from mwe]

which creates an extra white space to the right of the second matrix. I have notice that it happens when I make use of the matrix.skeleton library by means of label skeleton. However, I can not find the solution in the manual of the package from CTAN.

Comment: I think this might be a bug in the `matrix.skeleton` library.  In more detail, in `pgflibrarymatrix.skeleton.code.tex` all sorts of dimensions are stored in *global* macros, and get thus remembered in the second matrix. Rather than looking for workarounds or suggestions not to use the `label skeleton`, I'd recommend to report the issue to the package author.

Comment: There seem to be even deeper problems. Just commenting out the first matrix triggers an error on my updated TeXLive2019 installation.

Comment: Then I will report the issue to the maintainer.

Comment: The maintainer confirmed the existence of the bug but there is no fix yet, just the workaround.

Comment: I have posted an answer that gathers all the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### New answer

This `matrix.skeleton` library has been designed to simplify the use of the `fit` library. But it is [no longer maintained](https://github.com/dudebout/matrix.skeleton/issues/3#issuecomment-583851842). Here you just have to use the `fit` library which does not pose any of the problems that `matrix.skeleton` is supposed to solve. 
[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}


\matrix (X) [matrix of math nodes,
            %label skeleton,
             left delimiter  = (,
             right delimiter = )] at (0,0)
{%
  \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots  \\
  x & x & \cdots & x \\
  \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots  \\
  x & x & \cdots & x\\
  \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots  \\
  x & x & \cdots & x\\
  \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots  \\
  x & x & \cdots & x\\
  \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots  \\
  x & x & \cdots & x\\
};

\matrix (U) [matrix of math nodes,
            %label skeleton,
             left delimiter  = (,
             right delimiter = )] at (4.5,0)
{
  \vdots  \\
  u\\
  \vdots \\
  u\\
  \vdots \\
  u\\
  \vdots \\
  u\\
  \vdots \\
  u\\
};

%\fitandstyle{(X-cell-2-1) (X-cell-6-4)}{draw=red, fill=red!25, opacity=0.5}
%\fitandstyle{(U-cell-4-1) (U-cell-8-1)}{draw=red, fill=red!25, opacity=0.5,xshift=-4.5cm}
\node [fit=(X-2-1) (X-6-4),draw=red, fill=red!25, opacity=0.5,inner sep=0pt]{};
\node [fit=(U-4-1) (U-8-1),draw=red, fill=red!25, opacity=0.5,inner sep=0pt]{};
\draw[red,dashed] (X-2-4.north east) -- (U-4-1.north west);
\draw[red,dashed] (X-6-4.south east) -- (U-8-1.south west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

#### Old answer

By not using the matrix.skeleton package for the second matrix, everything works normally.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix.skeleton}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (X) [matrix of math nodes,
            label skeleton,
             left delimiter  = (,
             right delimiter = )] at (0,0)
{%
  \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots  \\
  x & x & \cdots & x \\
  \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots  \\
  x & x & \cdots & x\\
  \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots  \\
  x & x & \cdots & x\\
  \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots  \\
  x & x & \cdots & x\\
  \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots  \\
  x & x & \cdots & x\\
};

\matrix (U) [matrix of math nodes,
            %label skeleton,
             left delimiter  = (,
             right delimiter = )] at (4,0)
{%
  \vdots  \\
  u\\
  \vdots \\
  u\\
  \vdots \\
  u\\
  \vdots \\
  u\\
  \vdots \\
  u\\
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But I need it for highlighting and other stuff.

Comment: In this case, modify your question so that your constraints are taken into account.

Comment: I already expressed my will to highlight some things and so on in the question. Anyway I will change it in case if was not clear enough.

Comment: Your code as written does not need to use the skeleton library, so if there are constraints that led you to use this library, they must be present in the code.

Comment: Ok I have edited it again. Now it should meet the requirements.

Comment: @Fabio I've updated my answer.

Comment: Great edit code! :-)

Answer (score 1):

As the other guys, I think that there are issues in the `matrix.skeleton` library.

The space on the right side is exactly as wide, as the x-coordinate (If the x-coordinate is negative, the space in on the left side.) The y-coordiante effects the same problem at the top and the bottom of the matrix.

You could do the following as workaround:

```
\documentclass[
    tikz
    ]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix.skeleton}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\matrix (X) [matrix of math nodes,
            label skeleton,
            left delimiter  = (,
            right delimiter = )]
{%
  \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots  \\
  x & x & \cdots & x \\
  \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots  \\
  x & x & \cdots & x\\
  \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots  \\
  x & x & \cdots & x\\
  \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots  \\
  x & x & \cdots & x\\
  \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots  \\
  x & x & \cdots & x\\
};

\node () at (4, 0){
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (U) [matrix of math nodes,
                 label skeleton,
                 left delimiter  = (,
                 right delimiter = )]
    {
      \vdots  \\
      u\\
      \vdots \\
      u\\
      \vdots \\
      u\\
      \vdots \\
      u\\
      \vdots \\
      u\\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I know it is very messy, but it works.

Comment: This did the trick.

Comment: Sorry to say this, but this nests `tikzpicture`s and is not a good answer IMHO. Nesting `tikzpicture`s is not supported.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I think you mean, that the solution is bad. Not the answer. Isn't it ? Ofcourse you are right. Netsting `tikzpicture`s are bad style. Because of that, it's only a workaround. But what do you mean with nesting `tikzpicture`s are not supported ?

Comment: It means that the maintainers of Ti*k*Z do not think it should be used, nor will work on making it a safe-to-use option. If you do nest `tikzpicture`s you will more or less inevitably run into major problems at some point.

Comment: Thx good to know, that it is not a safe-to-use option.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the matrix.skeleton tikz library. The maintainer is informed. There is not a fix yet.